# snap packages error "multiple nvidia drivers detected, this is not supported"

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, snap

This issue happened after running updates. I've checked the system but only one Nvidia driver seems to be present. Purging / reinstalling the Nvidia drivers didn't fix it. Nor did purging / reinstalling the snap system. Could it have something to do with nvidia-prime? How does it check for the issue?

Answer (score -1):

The update failed to remove the folder nvidia-361 which contained two broken symlinks. Removing this folder resolved the issue.

Comment: Removed which folder? Can you specify the full path please?

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)